# How to not die of starvation in Hardcore Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have recently been trying to play Hardcore Minecraft. However, I keep dying of starvation. How do I not die of starvation in Hardcore Minecraft?

Comment: find an early source of food. I find that often times killing cod / salmon is an easy early food supply until you've found a better, more stable source (e.g. making a meat / chicken farm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [hunger system](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger#Mechanics) utilizes four variables to control players' abilities, the values of which are stored in the player.dat format.

An important thing is the "Exhaustion Level". Swimming, breaking blocks, sprinting, jumping, melee, jump sprinting all increase the exhaustion level.

In general try to walk more instead of sprint jumping, especially when you do not have a stable food supply. Also, avoid all kinds of damage. The meager fall damage you received after jumping off a 4 block tall house would come back at you since the hunger bar would be used to regenerate your HP. Lastly, kill as much chickens, cows, sheep, pigs as possible.